# Best wiki engine to use?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm looking to set up a wiki as a simple CMS for a resource page. Mostly just pdfs and word documents will be hosted, but the two main features I'm looking for is the ability to restrict pages based upon user privileges and for blog-style comments between the users.

From what I've researched, mediawiki can easily do the first part with restricting users, but I haven't had much luck finding any plugins for comments. I'm trying to avoid the discussion style pages from wikipedia, and have more of a comments just under the article.

So far I'm leaning towards trying Tiki out, any other recommendations?

Comment: If you do not care whether comments are hosted on-site for SEO purposes you could use MediaWiki with a skin which references a third-party comment provider - i.e. http://disqus.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [ScrewTurn](http://www.screwturn.eu/) wiki before now, very simple to set up and use - but it does need a Microsoft server to run on (Windows Server 2003 or Windows Server 2008).

There is a [sandbox on the ScrewTurn website](http://www.screwturn.eu/Sandbox.ashx) to try out how it works - so you can try it before having to install it, and even if it isn't for you it may give you sone ideas of what you do want.

Answer (score 0):

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/pricing.jsp) does those things and is a good price provided you have less than 10 users - $10.